# Is there a way I can join two tables and then group by a field in one of the tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: Phrase and PhraseCategory

They are linked with `Phrase.CategoryId` == `PhraseCategory.PhraseCategoryShortId`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]   INT              NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PhraseCategory] (
    [PhraseCategoryShortId] INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name]                  VARCHAR (100)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseCategoryShortId] ASC)
);
```

Can someone help give me some advice on how I can join these so that I get a report looking like this:

```
PhraseCategory.Name        Qty
```

Where Qty is the number of Phrases that are in each category.

What I need also is the have the report sorted in order of PhraseCategory.Name

Comment: Could u update your Question via adding some sample data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something this i`s just a join

If you only want the phrase categories that have a Phrase entry

```
SELECT PhraseCategory.name, count(*) AS qty
  FROM Phrase
  JOIN PhraseCategory
    ON Phrase.CategoryId = PhraseCategory.PhraseCategoryShortId
 GROUP BY PhraseCategory.name
```

Or use LEFT JOIN if you interested in all names including the ones with no Phrase entries

Comment: But how I can order this by the PhraseCategory.name ?

Comment: Just add `ORDER BY PhraseCategory.name`

Answer (score 0):

If You join them, at start of the query You are writing `SELECT ColA, ColB, ...`, You can make GROUP BY on this after. It will look like:

```
SELECT Sum( ColC ), ColA, ColB
   FROM (
       SELECT t1.ColA, t1.ColB, t2.ColC
       FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
       WHERE t1.ColB = t2.ColB) r
GROUP BY r.ColC
```